# How to access function inside controller which is inside directive? Everything returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine

This is my directive mySchedule.directive.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('mySchedule', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            mine: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'App/directives/mySchedule.html?v={version}',

        controller: ['$scope', 'utils', '$location',
            function ($scope, utils, $location) {
                $scope.navigateToMySchedule = function (name) {
                  utils.showConfirmationDialog(
                    myResources.resourceText.alert_Navigation, 
                    myResources.resourceText.confirmDialog_LeaveCurrentPage, 
                    'Leave page', 'Stay on page').result.then(function () {
                        $location.path("/myCar/").search("route", name);
                    //on ok button press 
                    // end on ok button press
                }, function () {
                    //on cancel button press
                });
            }
        }]
    };
});
```

And this is my testing file
mySchedule.directive.spec.js

```
/// <reference path="../../../chutzpah.conf.js" />
'use strict';


describe('mySchedule Directive', function () {
    var $httpBackend;
    var $scope;
    var $compile;
    var utilsService;
    var $location;
    var controller;
    var $controller;

    beforeEach(module('myApp', function ($provide) {

    }));

    beforeEach(
        inject(function ($rootScope, _$compile_, $injector, _$location_, utils, _$controller_) {
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            $httpBackend.whenGET('App/directives/mySchedule.html').respond(200, 'OK');
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $location = _$location_;
            $controller = _$controller_;
            utilsService = utils
            utilsService.showconfirmationdialog = function () {
            return true;
            }
        })
    );

    afterEach(function () {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    });

    it('should redirect to my schedule', function () {
        var element = angular.element('<my-schedule></my-schedule');
        var testcase = "name"
        element = $compile(element)($scope);
        //$httpBackend.flush();
        $scope.$digest();

        // NOW NONE OF THESE LINES AFTER THIS WORK

        element.isolateScope().navigateToMySchedule(testcase);
        var controller = $controller('mySchedule', { '$scope': $scope });
        $scope.navigateToMySchedule(testcase);
        controller.navigateToMySchedule(testcase);
        expect(location.path).toEqual("/route=name");
    });
});
```

- controller is undefined
- element.isolateScope() is undefined
- $scope.navigateToMySchedule(testcase) gives Object doesn't support property or method 'navigateToMySchedule' error

Comment: As a heads-up, there is a difference between [angular] and [angularjs]. The difference being that the [angular] tag is for Angular 2+ questions and the [angularjs] tag is for 1.x questions. I suggest you update your tags to increase your chances of getting helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that nothing is *overwritting* the function `module` and that you are including `ngMock`. One way to be sure is to call `angular.mock.module` directly, something like

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp', function ($provide) {}));
```

Using `$httpBackend` for *mocking* `templateUrl` won't work, right now, your `directive` is not being created and thus all your code failing.

One easy and simple way could be using `$templateCache`

```
beforeEach(function () {
    $templateCache.put('App/directives/mySchedule.html', '<div>OK</div>');
});
```

Now, if your *template* was *mocked* successfully, calling `element.isolateScope()` should be fine, but not the lines after.

`$controller` check if a controller with given name is registered via `$controllerProvider` and if evaluating the string on the current scope returns a constructor, your controller is declared inline in the `directive` so it won't be found. If you want to get the controller, use `element.controller('mySchedule')`.

`controller.navigateToMySchedule` will fail because the function is in the `$scope` and not in the controller, I mean, you declare the function as `$scope.navigateToMySchedule = function (name)` and not as `this.navigateToMySchedule = function (name)`. Note the difference?

`$scope.navigateToMySchedule` will fail because the variable `$scope` does not contain the directive's scope. Calling `element.isolateScope()` is enough, right? But you can also get it using `element.children().scope()`.

Here is a small test I did locally to mimic yours.

Fist, the module and directive:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp', []);

})();

(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('mySchedule', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                mine: '='
            },
            templateUrl: 'App/directives/mySchedule.html',
            controller: function ($scope) {
                this.navigateToMySchedule = function (name) {
                    return name;
                }
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

And here the test

```
describe('mySchedule Directive', function () {
    var $scope;
    var $compile;
    var $templateCache;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp', function ($provide) {}));

    beforeEach(
        inject(['$rootScope', '$compile', '$templateCache',
            function ($rootScope, _$compile, _$templateCache) {
                $scope = $rootScope.$new();
                $compile = _$compile;
                $templateCache = _$templateCache;
        }])
    );

    beforeEach(function () {
        $templateCache.put('App/directives/mySchedule.html', '<div>OK</div>');
    });

    it("$scope should exist", function () {
        expect($scope).toBeDefined();
        expect($compile).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should redirect to my schedule', function () {
        var element = angular.element('<my-schedule></my-schedule');
        var testcase = "name"
        element = $compile(element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();

        var controller = element.controller('mySchedule');
        expect(controller).toBeDefined();
        expect(controller.navigateToMySchedule).toBeDefined();
        expect(controller.navigateToMySchedule(testcase)).toEqual(testcase);
    });
});
```

Please, note that I'm only injecting what I needed to run this test, you could need more. Also, I'm using `this` in the `directive` to declare the function `navigateToMySchedule` so I can call it from the controller instance.

Well, hope it helps